# Sorting multiple divs with multiple attributes with jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-sortable

I'm looking for a solution to sort / append multiple divs with multiple attributes on the fly using jquery.

E.g.

```
<div class="rating" data-industry="1" data-use="7" data-platform="5" data-score="9">Sample 1</div>
<div class="rating" data-industry="3" data-use="2" data-platform="5" data-score="3">Sample 1</div>
<div class="rating" data-industry="4" data-use="7" data-platform="7" data-score="4">Sample 1</div>
<div class="rating" data-industry="5" data-use="1" data-platform="3" data-score="5">Sample 1</div>
```

So we then have a number of selects to sort the data:

```
<select name="sortindustry" id="sortindustry">
      <option value="">Please select...</option>
      <option  value="1">Art & Design</option>
      <option  value="2">Education</option>
      <option  value="3">Environmental & Ethical</option>                
</select>

<select name="sortuse" id="sortuse">
          <option value="">Please select...</option>
          <option  value="1">Seed</option>
          <option  value="2">Growth</option>
          <option  value="3">Other</option>                
    </select>
```

I have found it easy to sort using one attribute, usually the id but struggling to find a stable solution to sort multiple attributes, any help is very much appreciated :-)

Comment: See my answer for sorting elements based on specified attributes. As an aside, if you're mistaken in what you're asking for an you actually mean sort multiple attributes *simultaneously* (i.e. sort by industry and *then* by platform), include it in your question.

Comment: Yes I'm looking to sort simultaineously, so industry and platform etc.. but only if the select has a value

Answer (score 1):

```
<select name="sortindustry" id="sortindustry" class="sort-control" data-sort-attr="industry">
      <option value="">Please select...</option>
      <option  value="1">Art & Design</option>
      <option  value="2">Education</option>
      <option  value="3">Environmental & Ethical</option>                
</select>

$('.sort-control').change(function()
{
     var attribute = $(this).attr('data-sort-attr');
     $('.rating').sort(function (a, b) {
          var valueA = parseInt( $(a).attr('data-' + attribute));
          var contentB = parseInt( $(b).attr('data-' + attribute));
          return (valueA < valueB ) ? -1 : (valueA > valueB ) ? 1 : 0;
       });
});
```

**Explanation**

Changes have been made to the select. I've added a class, so that you can attach an event handler to all 'sort-controls'.

On the value of a `sort-control` changing, I retrieve the attribute by which the rating elements are to be sorted by.

And then call sort based on this `data-sort-attr`, which basically allows you to define comparison logic.

Answer (score 1):

I have found a good way to filter:

```
<script>
$(function(){
  // bind change event to select
  $('.sortselect').bind('change', function () {
      var url = $(this).val(); // get selected value
      if (url) { // require a URL

          if (this.val == '') {
            $('.rating2').fadeIn(450);
          } else {
            var $el = $('.' + url).fadeIn(450);
            $('.rating2').not($el).hide();
          }
          $btns.removeClass('active');
          $(this).addClass('active');

      }
      return false;
  });
});
```

Then each DIV looks like this:

```
<div class="rating2 internet expansion crowdcube"></div>
```

My question now is how can I ensure it works with multiple selections, so if I select internet THEN expansion, divs with the class internet and expansion will show and the rest will hide?